# Where should I implement my facebook ios sdk code in my Cocos2d Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to add facebook integration to my ios game built using Cocos2D.  I initially just made the CCLayer object (subclass of NSObject) a FBRequestDelegate, FBDialogDelegate, and FBSessionDelegate.  Then I created a facebook object with

```
fb_permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        @"read_stream", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain];

facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId
                                   andDelegate:self];
```

next I call

```
[facebook authorize:fb_permissions];
```

when the user pushes a button.  It all works fine, goes to the facebook login page, correctly authorizes my application etc.  Once it returns execution to my game, I expected the

```
- (void)fbDidLogin
```

method to be called, but it doesn't seem to be.  I'm a little confused and just wondering if I've gone about this wrong?  Should I implement my facebook sdk stuff in my root viewcontroller? ie. make my viewcontroller the FB delegate?

Is it that I'm missing a call to handleOpenURL?  Which appears to be depracated?  I'm having trouble locating decent documentation on this particular issue...

thanks!!

Comment: looks like I needed the handleOpenURL call in my app delegate.  I moved all the FB stuff into my viewcontroller, and added the call to handleOpenURL to my delegate and everything seems to be working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to implement handleOpenURL in your App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

Edit: I see that execution returns to your game, so you may have already completed the following:

You will also need to edit your .plist file to handle the return from the authorization page.  You will add an entry to `MyApp-info.plist` under

```
Information Property List->URL Types->Item 0->URL Schemes->Item 0 = "fbYOUR_APP_ID"
```

Follow the instructions at the end of Step 6 here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios